# I want to save UISegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex in Core Data - but how

Tags: ios, core-data, uisegmentedcontrol

I am using a segmented control as a kind of radio button system for a contact app.
There is three buttons, and the questions is if the contact is an existing customer.
The names of the buttons are "No", "Yes", "Other Division"

I am absolutely green in developing iOS, and this one is pulling my last remaining grey hairs out

I want to be able to save the selectedSegmentIndex value in the db of Core Data, so i can show the status on the next view correctly - but i am really struggling to get my head around, how to save the value:

```
if (self.existCustSelection.selectedSegmentIndex == 2)
    [self.currentContact setExistCust:[existCustSelection stringWithFormat:@"%d", @"2"]];
```

-This gives a compile error for

> No visible @Interface for 'UISegmentedControl' declares the selector 'stringWithFormat:'

I do understand that - my issue is, i want to set the `existCust` instead of `existCustSelection`, but for whatever reason, i don't get that option during writing the code.

My read goes like this and gives no error or warning:

```
if ([currentContact existCust] == @"2") {
            self.existCustSelection.selectedSegmentIndex = 2;
    }
```

Hopefully, there is a great solution out there? :)

Thanks in advance,
Mickey

Comment: What's the definition of `existCust`?  If it's a NSString, you should be able to use `[self.currentContact setExistCust:@"2"];` but then the `if` statement should use `isEqualTo` instead of `==`.

Comment: Phillip - absolutely correct! :)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Does existCust have to be a string?  If it only ever stores numbers, consider using `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber* custNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:existCustSelection.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

If you definitely do need a string, here's how to convert your index to a string using stringWithFormat:

```
NSString* custString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", existCustSelection.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

There are two problems with your call to `stringWithFormat`:

1. `stringWithFormat` is a class method of `NSString`.  You're asking your instance of `UISegmentedControl` to return a string, and it doesn't know how to do that.
2. Having requested a `%d` in stringWithFormat, the first argument needs to be an integer, such as `2`, not the string `@"2"`.